# Calendar into tables using Bootstrap

Tags: html, design-patterns, bootstrap-4

how can make this type of a table of this table that contains every days on months of this year (see the image ) any suggestion how i can made it or framework i can use

[image: Image representation]

Answer (score 0):

here some thing can help

```js
/**
 * Zabuto Calendar
 *
 * Dependencies
 * - jQuery (2.0.3)
 * - Twitter Bootstrap (3.0.2)
 */

if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
  throw new Error('jQuery is not loaded');
}

/**
 * Create calendar
 *
 * @param options
 * @returns {*}
 */
$.fn.zabuto_calendar = function(options) {
  var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.zabuto_calendar_defaults(), options);
  var languageSettings = $.fn.zabuto_calendar_language(opts.language);
  opts = $.extend({}, opts, languageSettings);

  this.each(function() {
    var $calendarElement = $(this);
    $calendarElement.attr('id', "zabuto_calendar_" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 99999).toString(36));

    $calendarElement.data('initYear', opts.year);
    $calendarElement.data('initMonth', opts.month);
    $calendarElement.data('monthLabels', opts.month_labels);
    $calendarElement.data('weekStartsOn', opts.weekstartson);
    $calendarElement.data('navIcons', opts.nav_icon);
    $calendarElement.data('dowLabels', opts.dow_labels);
    $calendarElement.data('showToday', opts.today);
    $calendarElement.data('showDays', opts.show_days);
    $calendarElement.data('showPrevious', opts.show_previous);
    $calendarElement.data('showNext', opts.show_next);
    $calendarElement.data('cellBorder', opts.cell_border);
    $calendarElement.data('jsonData', opts.data);
    $calendarElement.data('ajaxSettings', opts.ajax);
    $calendarElement.data('legendList', opts.legend);
    $calendarElement.data('actionFunction', opts.action);
    $calendarElement.data('actionNavFunction', opts.action_nav);

    drawCalendar();

    function drawCalendar() {
      var dateInitYear = parseInt($calendarElement.data('initYear'));
      var dateInitMonth = parseInt($calendarElement.data('initMonth')) - 1;
      var dateInitObj = new Date(dateInitYear, dateInitMonth, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
      $calendarElement.data('initDate', dateInitObj);

      var tableClassHtml = ($calendarElement.data('cellBorder') === true) ? ' table-bordered' : '';

      $tableObj = $('<table class="table' + tableClassHtml + '"></table>');
      $tableObj = drawTable($calendarElement, $tableObj, dateInitObj.getFullYear(), dateInitObj.getMonth());

      $legendObj = drawLegend($calendarElement);

      var $containerHtml = $('<div class="zabuto_calendar" id="' + $calendarElement.attr('id') + '"></div>');
      $containerHtml.append($tableObj);
      $containerHtml.append($legendObj);

      $calendarElement.append($containerHtml);

      var jsonData = $calendarElement.data('jsonData');
      if (false !== jsonData) {
        checkEvents($calendarElement, dateInitObj.getFullYear(), dateInitObj.getMonth());
      }
    }

    function drawTable($calendarElement, $tableObj, year, month) {
      var dateCurrObj = new Date(year, month, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
      $calendarElement.data('currDate', dateCurrObj);

      $tableObj.empty();
      $tableObj = appendMonthHeader($calendarElement, $tableObj, year, month);
      $tableObj = appendDayOfWeekHeader($calendarElement, $tableObj);
      $tableObj = appendDaysOfMonth($calendarElement, $tableObj, year, month);
      checkEvents($calendarElement, year, month);
      return $tableObj;
    }

    function drawLegend($calendarElement) {
      var $legendObj = $('<div class="legend" id="' + $calendarElement.attr('id') + '_legend"></div>');
      var legend = $calendarElement.data('legendList');
      if (typeof(legend) == 'object' && legend.length > 0) {
        $(legend).each(function(index, item) {
          if (typeof(item) == 'object') {
            if ('type' in item) {
              var itemLabel = '';
              if ('label' in item) {
                itemLabel = item.label;
              }

              switch (item.type) {
                case 'text':
                  if (itemLabel !== '') {
                    var itemBadge = '';
                    if ('badge' in item) {
                      if (typeof(item.classname) === 'undefined') {
                        var badgeClassName = 'badge-event';
                      } else {
                        var badgeClassName = item.classname;
                      }
                      itemBadge = '<span class="badge ' + badgeClassName + '">' + item.badge + '</span> ';
                    }
                    $legendObj.append('<span class="legend-' + item.type + '">' + itemBadge + itemLabel + '</span>');
                  }
                  break;
                case 'block':
                  if (itemLabel !== '') {
                    itemLabel = '<span>' + itemLabel + '</span>';
                  }
                  if (typeof(item.classname) === 'undefined') {
                    var listClassName = 'event';
                  } else {
                    var listClassName = 'event-styled ' + item.classname;
                  }
                  $legendObj.append('<span class="legend-' + item.type + '"><ul class="legend"><li class="' + listClassName + '"></li></u>' + itemLabel + '</span>');
                  break;
                case 'list':
                  if ('list' in item && typeof(item.list) == 'object' && item.list.length > 0) {
                    var $legendUl = $('<ul class="legend"></u>');
                    $(item.list).each(function(listIndex, listClassName) {
                      $legendUl.append('<li class="' + listClassName + '"></li>');
                    });
                    $legendObj.append($legendUl);
                  }
                  break;
                case 'spacer':
                  $legendObj.append('<span class="legend-' + item.type + '"> </span>');
                  break;

              }
            }
          }
        });
      }

      return $legendObj;
    }

    function appendMonthHeader($calendarElement, $tableObj, year, month) {
      var navIcons = $calendarElement.data('navIcons');
      var $prevMonthNavIcon = $('<span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></span>');
      var $nextMonthNavIcon = $('<span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></span>');
      if (typeof(navIcons) === 'object') {
        if ('prev' in navIcons) {
          $prevMonthNavIcon.html(navIcons.prev);
        }
        if ('next' in navIcons) {
          $nextMonthNavIcon.html(navIcons.next);
        }
      }

      var prevIsValid = $calendarElement.data('showPrevious');
      if (typeof(prevIsValid) === 'number' || prevIsValid === false) {
        prevIsValid = checkMonthLimit($calendarElement.data('showPrevious'), true);
      }

      var $prevMonthNav = $('<div class="calendar-month-navigation"></div>');
      $prevMonthNav.attr('id', $calendarElement.attr('id') + '_nav-prev');
      $prevMonthNav.data('navigation', 'prev');
      if (prevIsValid !== false) {
        prevMonth = (month - 1);
        prevYear = year;
        if (prevMonth == -1) {
          prevYear = (prevYear - 1);
          prevMonth = 11;
        }
        $prevMonthNav.data('to', {
          year: prevYear,
          month: (prevMonth + 1)
        });
        $prevMonthNav.append($prevMonthNavIcon);
        if (typeof($calendarElement.data('actionNavFunction')) === 'function') {
          $prevMonthNav.click($calendarElement.data('actionNavFunction'));
        }
        $prevMonthNav.click(function(e) {
          drawTable($calendarElement, $tableObj, prevYear, prevMonth);
        });
      }

      var nextIsValid = $calendarElement.data('showNext');
      if (typeof(nextIsValid) === 'number' || nextIsValid === false) {
        nextIsValid = checkMonthLimit($calendarElement.data('showNext'), false);
      }

      var $nextMonthNav = $('<div class="calendar-month-navigation"></div>');
      $nextMonthNav.attr('id', $calendarElement.attr('id') + '_nav-next');
      $nextMonthNav.data('navigation', 'next');
      if (nextIsValid !== false) {
        nextMonth = (month + 1);
        nextYear = year;
        if (nextMonth == 12) {
          nextYear = (nextYear + 1);
          nextMonth = 0;
        }
        $nextMonthNav.data('to', {
          year: nextYear,
          month: (nextMonth + 1)
        });
        $nextMonthNav.append($nextMonthNavIcon);
        if (typeof($calendarElement.data('actionNavFunction')) === 'function') {
          $nextMonthNav.click($calendarElement.data('actionNavFunction'));
        }
        $nextMonthNav.click(function(e) {
          drawTable($calendarElement, $tableObj, nextYear, nextMonth);
        });
      }

      var monthLabels = $calendarElement.data('monthLabels');

      var $prevMonthCell = $('<th></th>').append($prevMonthNav);
      var $nextMonthCell = $('<th></th>').append($nextMonthNav);

      var $currMonthLabel = $('<span>' + monthLabels[month] + ' ' + year + '</span>');
      $currMonthLabel.dblclick(function() {
        var dateInitObj = $calendarElement.data('initDate');
        drawTable($calendarElement, $tableObj, dateInitObj.getFullYear(), dateInitObj.getMonth());
      });

      var $currMonthCell = $('<th colspan="5"></th>');
      $currMonthCell.append($currMonthLabel);

      var $monthHeaderRow = $('<tr class="calendar-month-header"></tr>');
      $monthHeaderRow.append($prevMonthCell, $currMonthCell, $nextMonthCell);

      $tableObj.append($monthHeaderRow);
      return $tableObj;
    }

    function appendDayOfWeekHeader($calendarElement, $tableObj) {
      if ($calendarElement.data('showDays') === true) {
        var weekStartsOn = $calendarElement.data('weekStartsOn');
        var dowLabels = $calendarElement.data('dowLabels');
        if (weekStartsOn === 0) {
          var dowFull = $.extend([], dowLabels);
          var sunArray = new Array(dowFull.pop());
          dowLabels = sunArray.concat(dowFull);
        }

        var $dowHeaderRow = $('<tr class="calendar-dow-header"></tr>');
        $(dowLabels).each(function(index, value) {
          $dowHeaderRow.append('<th>' + value + '</th>');
        });
        $tableObj.append($dowHeaderRow);
      }
      return $tableObj;
    }

    function appendDaysOfMonth($calendarElement, $tableObj, year, month) {
      var ajaxSettings = $calendarElement.data('ajaxSettings');
      var weeksInMonth = calcWeeksInMonth(year, month);
      var lastDayinMonth = calcLastDayInMonth(year, month);
      var firstDow = calcDayOfWeek(year, month, 1);
      var lastDow = calcDayOfWeek(year, month, lastDayinMonth);
      var currDayOfMonth = 1;

      var weekStartsOn = $calendarElement.data('weekStartsOn');
      if (weekStartsOn === 0) {
        if (lastDow == 6) {
          weeksInMonth++;
        }
        if (firstDow == 6 && (lastDow == 0 || lastDow == 1 || lastDow == 5)) {
          weeksInMonth--;
        }
        firstDow++;
        if (firstDow == 7) {
          firstDow = 0;
        }
      }

      for (var wk = 0; wk < weeksInMonth; wk++) {
        var $dowRow = $('<tr class="calendar-dow"></tr>');
        for (var dow = 0; dow < 7; dow++) {
          if (dow < firstDow || currDayOfMonth > lastDayinMonth) {
            $dowRow.append('<td></td>');
          } else {
            var dateId = $calendarElement.attr('id') + '_' + dateAsString(year, month, currDayOfMonth);
            var dayId = dateId + '_day';

            var $dayElement = $('<div id="' + dayId + '" class="day" >' + currDayOfMonth + '</div>');
            $dayElement.data('day', currDayOfMonth);

            if ($calendarElement.data('showToday') === true) {
              if (isToday(year, month, currDayOfMonth)) {
                $dayElement.html('<span class="badge badge-today">' + currDayOfMonth + '</span>');
              }
            }

            var $dowElement = $('<td id="' + dateId + '"></td>');
            $dowElement.append($dayElement);

            $dowElement.data('date', dateAsString(year, month, currDayOfMonth));
            $dowElement.data('hasEvent', false);

            if (typeof($calendarElement.data('actionFunction')) === 'function') {
              $dowElement.addClass('dow-clickable');
              $dowElement.click(function() {
                $calendarElement.data('selectedDate', $(this).data('date'));
              });
              $dowElement.click($calendarElement.data('actionFunction'));
            }

            $dowRow.append($dowElement);

            currDayOfMonth++;
          }
          if (dow == 6) {
            firstDow = 0;
          }
        }

        $tableObj.append($dowRow);
      }
      return $tableObj;
    }

    /* ----- Modal functions ----- */

    function createModal(id, title, body, footer) {
      var $modalHeaderButton = $('<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>');
      var $modalHeaderTitle = $('<h4 class="modal-title" id="' + id + '_modal_title">' + title + '</h4>');

      var $modalHeader = $('<div class="modal-header"></div>');
      $modalHeader.append($modalHeaderButton);
      $modalHeader.append($modalHeaderTitle);

      var $modalBody = $('<div class="modal-body" id="' + id + '_modal_body">' + body + '</div>');

      var $modalFooter = $('<div class="modal-footer" id="' + id + '_modal_footer"></div>');
      if (typeof(footer) !== 'undefined') {
        var $modalFooterAddOn = $('<div>' + footer + '</div>');
        $modalFooter.append($modalFooterAddOn);
      }

      var $modalContent = $('<div class="modal-content"></div>');
      $modalContent.append($modalHeader);
      $modalContent.append($modalBody);
      $modalContent.append($modalFooter);

      var $modalDialog = $('<div class="modal-dialog"></div>');
      $modalDialog.append($modalContent);

      var $modalFade = $('<div class="modal fade" id="' + id + '_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="' + id + '_modal_title" aria-hidden="true"></div>');
      $modalFade.append($modalDialog);

      $modalFade.data('dateId', id);
      $modalFade.attr("dateId", id);

      return $modalFade;
    }

    /* ----- Event functions ----- */

    function checkEvents($calendarElement, year, month) {
      var jsonData = $calendarElement.data('jsonData');
      var ajaxSettings = $calendarElement.data('ajaxSettings');

      $calendarElement.data('events', false);

      if (false !== jsonData) {
        return jsonEvents($calendarElement);
      } else if (false !== ajaxSettings) {
        return ajaxEvents($calendarElement, year, month);
      }

      return true;
    }

    function jsonEvents($calendarElement) {
      var jsonData = $calendarElement.data('jsonData');
      $calendarElement.data('events', jsonData);
      drawEvents($calendarElement, 'json');
      return true;
    }

    function ajaxEvents($calendarElement, year, month) {
      var ajaxSettings = $calendarElement.data('ajaxSettings');

      if (typeof(ajaxSettings) != 'object' || typeof(ajaxSettings.url) == 'undefined') {
        alert('Invalid calendar event settings');
        return false;
      }

      var data = {
        year: year,
        month: (month + 1)
      };

      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: ajaxSettings.url,
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json'
      }).done(function(response) {
        var events = [];
        $.each(response, function(k, v) {
          events.push(response[k]);
        });
        $calendarElement.data('events', events);
        drawEvents($calendarElement, 'ajax');
      });

      return true;
    }

    function drawEvents($calendarElement, type) {
      var jsonData = $calendarElement.data('jsonData');
      var ajaxSettings = $calendarElement.data('ajaxSettings');

      var events = $calendarElement.data('events');
      if (events !== false) {
        $(events).each(function(index, value) {
          var id = $calendarElement.attr('id') + '_' + value.date;
          var $dowElement = $('#' + id);
          var $dayElement = $('#' + id + '_day');

          $dowElement.data('hasEvent', true);

          if (typeof(value.title) !== 'undefined') {
            $dowElement.attr('title', value.title);
          }

          if (typeof(value.classname) === 'undefined') {
            $dowElement.addClass('event');
          } else {
            $dowElement.addClass('event-styled');
            $dayElement.addClass(value.classname);
          }

          if (typeof(value.badge) !== 'undefined' && value.badge !== false) {
            var badgeClass = (value.badge === true) ? '' : ' badge-' + value.badge;
            var dayLabel = $dayElement.data('day');
            $dayElement.html('<span class="badge badge-event' + badgeClass + '">' + dayLabel + '</span>');
          }

          if (typeof(value.body) !== 'undefined') {
            var modalUse = false;
            if (type === 'json' && typeof(value.modal) !== 'undefined' && value.modal === true) {
              modalUse = true;
            } else if (type === 'ajax' && 'modal' in ajaxSettings && ajaxSettings.modal === true) {
              modalUse = true;
            }

            if (modalUse === true) {
              $dowElement.addClass('event-clickable');

              var $modalElement = createModal(id, value.title, value.body, value.footer);
              $('body').append($modalElement);

              $('#' + id).click(function() {
                $('#' + id + '_modal').modal();
              });
            }
          }
        });
      }
    }

    /* ----- Helper functions ----- */

    function isToday(year, month, day) {
      var todayObj = new Date();
      var dateObj = new Date(year, month, day);
      return (dateObj.toDateString() == todayObj.toDateString());
    }

    function dateAsString(year, month, day) {
      d = (day < 10) ? '0' + day : day;
      m = month + 1;
      m = (m < 10) ? '0' + m : m;
      return year + '-' + m + '-' + d;
    }

    function calcDayOfWeek(year, month, day) {
      var dateObj = new Date(year, month, day, 0, 0, 0, 0);
      var dow = dateObj.getDay();
      if (dow == 0) {
        dow = 6;
      } else {
        dow--;
      }
      return dow;
    }

    function calcLastDayInMonth(year, month) {
      var day = 28;
      while (checkValidDate(year, month + 1, day + 1)) {
        day++;
      }
      return day;
    }

    function calcWeeksInMonth(year, month) {
      var daysInMonth = calcLastDayInMonth(year, month);
      var firstDow = calcDayOfWeek(year, month, 1);
      var lastDow = calcDayOfWeek(year, month, daysInMonth);
      var days = daysInMonth;
      var correct = (firstDow - lastDow);
      if (correct > 0) {
        days += correct;
      }
      return Math.ceil(days / 7);
    }

    function checkValidDate(y, m, d) {
      return m > 0 && m < 13 && y > 0 && y < 32768 && d > 0 && d <= (new Date(y, m, 0)).getDate();
    }

    function checkMonthLimit(count, invert) {
      if (count === false) {
        count = 0;
      }
      var d1 = $calendarElement.data('currDate');
      var d2 = $calendarElement.data('initDate');

      var months;
      months = (d2.getFullYear() - d1.getFullYear()) * 12;
      months -= d1.getMonth() + 1;
      months += d2.getMonth();

      if (invert === true) {
        if (months < (parseInt(count) - 1)) {
          return true;
        }
      } else {
        if (months >= (0 - parseInt(count))) {
          return true;
        }
      }
      return false;
    }
  }); // each()

  return this;
};

/**
 * Default settings
 *
 * @returns object
 *   language:          string,
 *   year:              integer,
 *   month:             integer,
 *   show_previous:     boolean|integer,
 *   show_next:         boolean|integer,
 *   cell_border:       boolean,
 *   today:             boolean,
 *   show_days:         boolean,
 *   weekstartson:      integer (0 = Sunday, 1 = Monday),
 *   nav_icon:          object: prev: string, next: string
 *   ajax:              object: url: string, modal: boolean,
 *   legend:            object array, [{type: string, label: string, classname: string}]
 *   action:            function
 *   action_nav:        function
 */
$.fn.zabuto_calendar_defaults = function() {
  var now = new Date();
  var year = now.getFullYear();
  var month = now.getMonth() + 1;
  var settings = {
    language: false,
    year: year,
    month: month,
    show_previous: true,
    show_next: true,
    cell_border: false,
    today: false,
    show_days: true,
    weekstartson: 1,
    nav_icon: false,
    data: false,
    ajax: false,
    legend: false,
    action: false,
    action_nav: false
  };
  return settings;
};

/**
 * Language settings
 *
 * @param lang
 * @returns {{month_labels: Array, dow_labels: Array}}
 */
$.fn.zabuto_calendar_language = function(lang) {
  if (typeof(lang) == 'undefined' || lang === false) {
    lang = 'en';
  }

  switch (lang.toLowerCase()) {


    case 'en':
      return {
        month_labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
        dow_labels: ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"]
      };
      break;


  }

};


$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#my-calendar").zabuto_calendar({
    legend: [{
        type: "text",
        label: "Special event",
        badge: "00"
      },
      {
        type: "block",
        label: "Regular event",
        classname: "purple"
      },
      {
        type: "spacer"
      },
      {
        type: "text",
        label: "Bad"
      },
      {
        type: "list",
        list: ["grade-1", "grade-2", "grade-3", "grade-4"]
      },
      {
        type: "text",
        label: "Good"
      }
    ],
    ajax: {
      url: "show_data.php?grade=1"
    }
  });
});
```

```css
/**
 * Zabuto Calendar
 */

div.zabuto_calendar {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div.zabuto_calendar .table {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div.zabuto_calendar .table th,
div.zabuto_calendar .table td {
  padding: 4px 2px;
  text-align: center;
}

div.zabuto_calendar .table tr th,
div.zabuto_calendar .table tr td {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

div.zabuto_calendar .table tr.calendar-month-header th {
  background-color: #fafafa;
}

div.zabuto_calendar .table tr.calendar-month-header th span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

div.zabuto_calendar .table tr.calendar-dow-header th {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

div.zabuto_calendar .table tr:last-child {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

div.zabuto_calendar .table tr.calendar-month-header th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
}

div.zabuto_calendar .table-bordered tr.calendar-month-header th {
  border-left: 0;
  border-right: 0;
}

div.zabuto_calendar .table-bordered tr.calendar-month-header th:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

div.zabuto_calendar div.calendar-month-navigation {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

div.zabuto_calendar tr.calendar-dow-header th,
div.zabuto_calendar tr.calendar-dow td {
  width: 14%;
}

div.zabuto_calendar .table tr td div.day {
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 7px;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
}


/* actions and events */

div.zabuto_calendar .table tr td.event div.day,
div.zabuto_calendar ul.legend li.event {
  background-color: #fff0c3;
}

div.zabuto_calendar .table tr td.dow-clickable,
div.zabuto_calendar .table tr td.event-clickable {
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* badge */

div.zabuto_calendar .badge-today,
div.zabuto_calendar div.legend span.badge-today {
  background-color: #357ebd;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: none;
}

div.zabuto_calendar .badge-event,
div.zabuto_calendar div.legend span.badge-event {
  background-color: #ff9b08;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: none;
}

div.zabuto_calendar .badge-event {
  font-size: 0.95em;
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-right: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
}


/* legend */

div.zabuto_calendar div.legend {
  margin-top: 5px;
  text-align: right;
}

div.zabuto_calendar div.legend span {
  color: #999999;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

div.zabuto_calendar div.legend span.legend-text:after,
div.zabuto_calendar div.legend span.legend-block:after,
div.zabuto_calendar div.legend span.legend-list:after,
div.zabuto_calendar div.legend span.legend-spacer:after {
  content: ' ';
}

div.zabuto_calendar div.legend span.legend-spacer {
  padding-left: 25px;
}

div.zabuto_calendar ul.legend>span {
  padding-left: 2px;
}

div.zabuto_calendar ul.legend {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none outside none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div.zabuto_calendar ul.legend li {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 11px;
  width: 11px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

div.zabuto_calendar ul.legend div.zabuto_calendar ul.legend li:first-child {
  margin-left: 7px;
}

div.zabuto_calendar ul.legend li:last-child {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

div.zabuto_calendar div.legend span.badge {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}


/* responsive */

@media (max-width: 979px) {
  div.zabuto_calendar .table th,
  div.zabuto_calendar .table td {
    padding: 2px 1px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div id="my-calendar"></div>

    </div>
    <!--(./col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"BELOW ROW:)-->
  </div>
  <!--(./row)-->
</div>
<!--(./COntainer")-->
```

Responsive Calendar with a table but i don't think it's bootstrap